# What does the "have you ever been known by any other name?" question mean on the UK visa application?

Tags: visas, uk, applications

Basically, I recently submitted an application for a standard uk visa and there was a section of the form that I initially answered, but eventually deleted from my application i.e."have you ever been known by any other name?". The question appeared ambiqious to me as I also interpreted it to mean if I had made older passports in any other names.

In reality on my previous applications, I always pled the fifth in this section, but because the new application wouldn't let me proceed to the next section, I filled that section, but eventually edited it out of my final application.

It is worthy of note that I have always ever maintained the same name on all my passports since inception in 2003, but at the same time, I also think I might at one point or another probably submitted school certificates in my original birth names during at least one of my previous 2 student visa applications.

Now, I am worried the ECO might interpret this as me purposely lying and wonder if I never had a maiden name etc. I would just like to know if it might affect my application. 
Hmm..I just did the below to save myself from heartache i.e.I wrote in (not free of charge though. It came with a charge) to cancel my application as it wasn't possible to make changes after submission.

Dear UKVI,
Please, it just occurred to me that I misunderstood some of the questions asked or didn't notice they were changes in some of the questions asked as against the last time I applied. In view of these unintended errors therefore, I hereby write to cancel my current application and pray you to put the processing of my daughters' own on hold until I file in a new application, which will be as soon as possible.

Comment: Can you elaborate what your other names are for?

Comment: If your other names are only nicknames and are not recorded in your passport or other ID, there's nothing to worry about.  The form is asking about other/previous legal names.

Comment: I am female, so it means I have a maiden name, qnd got another name ie my ex-huuby's surname after marriage. Unfortunately,  I have an history with UK immigration kind of since I have been applying since 2003. The first application was for a student visa that was denied. Something tells me I might have indicated both my maiden name and married names on that visa application. It is been really long, so I can't remember. I  know I have studk to the names on my passport with subsequent applications though (I can remember, since these are more recent).

Comment: I forgot to tell you,  my ex-hubby and I with the whole family have also applied many times and gotten their visitors visa. They are aware I am divorced from him since I submitted documentations to proof that in my lass successful visa application in 2004. My father's name is also always boldly written on all my forms. So based on all these, I  wouldn't know if they can detect something is fishy

Comment: Honestly speaking,  I did not choose to hide my identity for any reason as I have never comitted any crimes with those names. I just felt writing out all the names I am known by would remove some elements of consistency from my application as I never really indicated those names before on my previous ones. Something also tells me they might be able to connect the dots if they go through my old student application. This is because my birth names are what are written on my school certificate and other documents I used to prove I was indeed going to study then.

Comment: I am in this mess today because of the ghastly mistake I made when I went to apply for my first passport. The passport officer just gave me a form to fill without telling me those information would be what would appear on my passport and I casually wrote the easier versions of my name that everyone calls me by. The sh*t didn't hit the fan until he came out later to hand me the new passport. Thanks so much for tryig to help me by the way.

Comment: Hi greatone, my other names are my full birth names written on my birth certificate, which includes a middle name. The one I got my first passport with and has always used for subsequent passports has the shortened version of my first name and my ex-hubby's surname. Example: My birth names are Adekemi Adekunbi Jaiyesimi

Comment: Get scared when you are refused, and not until? There's nothing to little you can do right now.

Comment: We cannot predict whether or not you will be refused. Stay calm and come back if you receive an actual refusal letter.

Comment: To use 320(7a) or b, the ECO has to prove (burden of proof is on him) that you were dishonest. This doesn't seem like dishonesty at all. Relax.

Comment: Wow! I really hope so. Thanks for your kind reassurance  @greatone

Comment: Incidentally "plead the fifth" does not mean "I forgot  that" or "I didn't think it was important". It means "if I answer that question it will indicate I am guilty of a crime", so don't ever use the phrase with an immigration officer.

Comment: Oh! Thanks so much.  I used to think it just meant 'no comments '. Now I  know better.

Comment: I'm confused by "I filled that section, but eventually edited it out of my final application." Do you mean you just removed the question from the form? I don't believe it is optional, and there is no "pleading the fifth" on visa applications. Or did you start to answer it, then change your mind and answer no?

Comment: Although this post originated a long time ago it's worth noting for other people, reading it that "pleading the fifth" is an American concept related to the 5th amendment of there Consitution. It has no legal meaning in the UK.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> **1.3 Other names**
>
> (including any other names you are known by and/or any other names
>   that you have been known by) Any other names by which you are or have
>   been known, for example, maiden name, name at birth, if different.

Source: [UKVI](https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/589168/VAF1-guidance.pdf)

Another explanation, also from the UKVI, is very specific to your case.

> **1.3 Other names**
>
> These are any other names by which you have been known, for example,
>   your maiden name, name at birth, if different, professional name. If
>   you are a married woman or were previously married and have used
>   different names at any time please include these even if you have now
>   reverted to an original name.

Source: [UKVI](https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/261419/vaf10-guidance.pdf)

**IMO You did have to provide the other names**.

I can't predict the outcome of your application, but it is clear from those guidance notes to me that the name you had on your birth certificate was supposed to be listed on the application, even if it is different now.

> It is worthy of note that I have always ever maintained the same name on all my passports since inception in 2003, but at the same time, I also think I might at one point or another probably submitted school certificates in my original birth names during at least one of my previous 2 student visa applications.

You absolutely have had multiple legal names. Passport is not the only identity document that a person can have. What about those people who have never had a passport? Birth certificates, National ID cards, Driving Licenses, Educational documents are all candidates of such an identity match review.

I would have listed the other name on my application with an explanation that i honestly missed mentioning this on my previous applications. Whether this is detrimental to your application we really don't know. It might not be very significant if the rest of your application is good. However only their decision can answer that part. Best of Luck!

Comment: thanks so much for your useful explanation. Like I already edited in in my question above, I just wrote to witdraw my application and I intend sending in a new one as soon as possible as I don't want to jeopardise my daughters ' Xmas holiday dreams. Hopefully, I succeed with the new application. In the light of this, how do you advise I navigate round my having never written my other legal names in all of my previous applications in the new one I plan on sending? And thanks in advance!

Comment: Im really not the right person to be able to suggest a course of action for a successful application. However if i was in this position I would apply with the correct facts and provide an explanation of why i did not provide the information before and try hard to dispel any suggestion that i was trying to hide something or game the system.

Comment: actually like I said in my original post, the question was always optional in the previous forms as I have never answered it before. The new form on the other hand is constructed in such a manner that one cannot skip any question as it wouldn't let you proceed without comitting to an answer. Once you are done filling the form though, it brings out all the form in a printable form and then gives you the ability to correct any mistakes before you click the final send button. I was able to edit that  section out of my form like that.

Comment: To my chagrin, even though I deleted that entire section from my form before pressing submit, I found out that when I eventually printed it out my form to take to the interview , it had automatically restored that section back and also selected a 'no' answer for me on its own. The old form was never like this. I was always able to ignore the question with the previous forms.

Comment: Would Dwayne Johnson have to write "The Rock"?

Comment: Would someone in witness protection have to declare the name they had in their previous life?

Comment: @Vikki Great question! You should ask it (probably on [law.se]).